# How to write under braces in the following latex code

Tags: underbrace

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{cite}  
\usepackage{nth}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
$$1,\underbrace{\frac{1}{2^2},\frac{1}{2^2},\frac{1}{2^2},\frac{1}{2^2}}_\text{2^2 times},\frac{1}{6^2},\frac{1}{8^2},\frac{1}{9^2},\frac{1}{10^2},\frac{1}{11^2},\frac{1}{12^2},\frac{1}{13^2},
\underbrace{\frac{1}{14^2},\frac{1}{14^2},\cdots,\frac{1}{14^2}}_\text{ times},\cdots$$
\end{document}
```

I am trying to write under braces. But it is not coming. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{cite}  
\usepackage{nth}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\begin{document}
\[
1,\underbrace{\frac{1}{2^2},\frac{1}{2^2},\frac{1}{2^2},\frac{1}{2^2}}_{\text{$2^2$ times}},\frac{1}{6^2},\frac{1}{8^2},\frac{1}{9^2},\frac{1}{10^2},\frac{1}{11^2},\frac{1}{12^2},\frac{1}{13^2},
\underbrace{\frac{1}{14^2},\frac{1}{14^2},\cdots,\frac{1}{14^2}}_{\text{ times}},\cdots
\]
\end{document}
```

PS: you have to place the second argument of `\underbrace` inside curly braces...

[image]

Comment: You lost the space between `2^2` and `times`. Either you write `2^2\text{ times}` or (IMO better) `\text{$2^2$ times}`.

Comment: Just to be _extremely_ fussy: `\text` would work in a subscript even without braces. But I completely agree that in most cases one must put them.

Comment: @campa ... "should"  ... but doesn't...

Comment: @koleygr Excuse me. Could you change your code putting \[...\] instead of $$...$$? The user have used the double dollars. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano ... Thanks for this improvement ... I hope that the OP will see your comment and visit here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to